# dart : how to check generic type of property?

Tags: dart

how to check the prop type when using it like this below

```dart
void main(){
  var obj = Ball<PassData>(data: PassData(id: 1,nama: 'asdas'));
  print('${obj.get()}');
}

class Ball<T>{
  T data;
  Ball({this.data});
  
  String get(){
    if(data is PassData){ //can't check it this way
      return 'this type has ${data.id} and ${data.nama}'; //compile error
    }
    else{
      return 'no : $data';
    }
  }
}

class PassData{
  String nama;
  int id;
  
  PassData({this.nama,this.id});
}
```

when using property of PassData object I've got an compile error like above. I need to get type of 'data' type property. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not that the type is generic, but that the variable is not a local variable.
Dart only promotes local variables, so doing `if (data is PassData)` doesn't promote the instance variable/field `data` to be a `PassData`.

Try writing it as:

```dart
  String get() {
    var data = this.data;
    if (data is PassData) {
      return 'this type has ${data.id} and ${data.nama}';
    } else {
      return 'no: $data';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your data is in T type and your get class does not know which class it is belong to and therefore can not handle the operations. You can try this:

```
String get(){
if(this.data is PassData){ 
  return 'this type has ${(data as PassData).id} and ${(data as PassData).nama}'; 
}
else{
  return 'no : $data';
}
```

}